# In Dockerfile "php artisan storage:link" returns a non-zero code

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I can't understand why this is happening. I am trying to create a symlink but it fails. It only works if I ssh into the container after it has been created. When I build my project using Docker I get this error message:

```
Step 11/14 : RUN php artisan storage:link
 ---> Running in bbfd87dcdbf6
Could not open input file: artisan
ERROR: Service 'php-container' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c php artisan storage:link' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But if I try to ssh into my container and run the same command **then it works**.

```
$ docker exec -it php-container /bin/bash

root@053d9cbd22eb:/var/www# php artisan storage:link
The [/var/www/public/storage] link has been connected to [/var/www/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    graphviz \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# Permissions for Laravel
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www

# (!) This is not working.......
RUN php artisan storage:link

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD bash -c "composer install && chmod -R 777 /var/www && php artisan migrate --seed && php-fpm"
```

Comment: To run an artisan command you need to have laravel already installed. Try moving the line `RUN php artisan storage:link` after this one `CMD bash -c "composer install && ..."`. Or something like `CMD bash -c "composer install && chmod -R 777 /var/www && php artisan migrate --seed && php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 2):

You must run composer install before php artisan command.
This is really important. you have error because artisan package not exist and actually vendor folder not created.

Finally you must change docker file to this :

```
CMD bash -c "composer install && chmod -R 777 /var/www && php artisan migrate --seed && php artisan storage:link
```